# Problem starting OWASP ZAP with OpenJDK 11 installed

Tags: java, installation, owasp

when I try to start OWASP ZAP, after installing, the following messages appears: "This application requires a Java Runtime Environment 1.8.0". I have installed OpenJDK 11 properly, updated the environment variables rightly. Could you help me, please?

Comment: What do you get it you run `java -version` from the command line?

Comment: Thank you Simon for replying. I get this: openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM AdoptOpenJDK (build openj9-0.24.0, JRE 11 Windows 10 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20210120_899 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 345e1b09e
OMR      - 741e94ea8
JCL      - 0a86953833 based on jdk-11.0.10+9)

Answer (score 28):

Try starting **zap.bat** file, that worked for me!

Comment: Starting the .bat worked very well, but why is the exe complaining about missing jre11 while java_home and path contains the java/bin path and java -version reports v11?

Comment: Worked for me as well. Much appreciation.

Answer (score 5):

Solution: Installing OpenJDK with the msi file. The installer has an option "JavaSoft (Oracle) registry keys". When this is activated, the 1.8.0 message disappears in my case. If it is not selected the error persists.

I encountered this error message recently on a Windows 10 machine when I wanted to run VOSViewer. I had installed Adopt OpenJDK by unzipping the files and updating the system variables (Path and JAVA_HOME). When checking java -version, it showed the correct one.

[MSI Installer options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoxOM.png)

Answer (score 5):

Try downloading and installing jdk 11 ,
Visit https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33071762)

Comment: Thank you Chandrapal, you saved me some time ;)

Comment: Also keep in mind that the error message also appears when a newer openJDK is installed (e.g. 19).
As downgrading might cause other problems, using the zap.bat as mentioned by IDM is still the best solution.

Comment: lucky me that tried your solution first and it worked :), thanks

Answer (score 4):

In my case using ZAP 2.12.0, the only solution that worked was to edit the zap.bat file, I had to specify the full path to the Java executable, so the last line becomes:

```
C:\jdk-17.0.5+8-jre\bin\java.exe %jvmopts% -jar "C:\Program Files\OWASP\Zed Attack Proxy\zap-2.12.0.jar" %*
```

Adjust for your JDK/JRE install directory as appropriate

Comment: You could alternatively add `C:\jdk-17.0.5+8-jre\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Install jdk from adoptium.net, it worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Install jdk from adoptium.net, it worked in my case too.
Tks Chi!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i just changed my zap.bat file to cd first to Java Bin directory
and put the full path of zap .jar file as follows, and worked like a charm
make your path changes:

```
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\OWASP ZAP\.ZAP_JVM.properties" (
    set /p jvmopts=< "%USERPROFILE%\OWASP ZAP\.ZAP_JVM.properties"
) else (
    set jvmopts=-Xmx512m
)
**cd "C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jre-17.0.7.7-hotspot\bin"**
java.exe %jvmopts% -jar **"C:\ZAP_2.13.0\zap-2.13.0.jar"** %*
```